A countable metric space implies totally disconnectedness
I'm stuck on a problem in general topology. But first, let's establish some observations:
Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space. The connected component of $x \in X$, denoted by $C(x)$, is the union of all connected subsets of $X$ that contain $x$.
We also know that the connected components of a space form a partition of it, in the sense that two components are either equal or disjoint.
Finally, we say that a topological space is totally disconnected if all its connected components are singletons.
That said, I am stuck on an exercise from the book Introduction to Topology by Gamelin, which states the following:
Prove that any countable metric space is totally disconnected.
The book gives the following hint: given $x \in X$, since the distance from $x$ to other points forms a countable set (Okay, this is clear to me), there exists a decreasing sequence $r_n \to 0$ such that $d(x,y) \neq r_n$ for all $y \in X$ and for all $n \geq 1$. Then the ball $B(x, r_n)$ is open and closed in $X$, so that, the ball contains $C(x)$, and since the ball shrinks to $x$, then the connected component of $x$ is $C(x) = \{x\}$.
I couldn't develop this idea. I didn't understand how I can construct this sequence. In fact, in general, I still have some difficulty developing these types of arguments.
Thanks for the help.

The map $d(x, \cdot): C(x) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. $C(x)$ is connected, so $\{d(x, y): y \in C(x)\}$ is connected and thus an interval. The set is also countable, but the only countable intervals are singletons, so $\{d(x, y): y \in C(x)\} = \{0\}$, that is, any $y \in C(x)$ satisfies $d(x, y) = 0$ and therefore $y = x$. To put it another way, $C(x) = \{x\}$.

Your argument looks so simple and nice to me, but I still do not understand why the set $\lbrace d(x,y) : y\in C(x)\rbrace = \lbrace 0\rbrace$. I mean, it is quite clear that this set must be a singleton in order to be a countable interval. But why does it contain specifically the real number zero?

@JoelMarques This is because $x \in C(x)$, so by definition of the set, $0 = d(x, x)$ is contained in that set (choose $y = x$).

Of course! Thank you for your help. It is a beautiful argument!

Developing the idea,
The set $ T =\{d(x,y) \ | \ y \in X\}$ is a countable subset of the non-negative real numbers. We construct the sequence $r_n$ as follows:
For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, choose $r_n \in (0,\frac{1}{n})$ such that $r_n \notin T$, $r_n < r_{n-1}$. This is possible because $T$ is countable whereas $(0, r_{n-1})$ isn't.
This sequence converges to $0$ by the squeeze theorem.
$B(x,r_n)$ is open by definition. It is also closed because its boundary $\{y \in X\ | \ d(x,y) = r_n\}$ is empty. It is easy to see that any open and closed subset containing $x$ must contain $C(x)$. Thus, $C(x) \subseteq \cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} B(x,r_n)$. But the later intersection is just $\{x\}$ as $r_n \to 0$.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that there is a (connected) component $S$ of the countable metric space $X$ that contains $x_1, x_2$, where $x_1 \ne x_2$. Let $\varepsilon = d (x_1, x_2) > 0$. The subset $B = B_d (x_1, \varepsilon)$ of $X$ is countable. Let $D = \{ d (x_1, x) | x \in B \} \subseteq [0, \varepsilon)$; $D$ is also countable. But the interval $[0, \varepsilon) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, so there must exist some $\delta \in [0, \varepsilon)$ such that $\delta \notin D$. Clearly, $\delta \ne 0$ since $d (x_1, x_1) = 0$, so $\delta \in (0, \varepsilon)$. Then the disjoint open sets $E = B_d (x_1, \delta)$ and $F = X - \text{Cl} B_d (x_1, \delta)$ of $X$ separate $S$, and each intersects $S$; e.g., $x_1 \in S \cap E$ and $x_2 \in S \cap F$. This contradicts the hypothesis that $S$ is connected.

I'm not sure if I understood your last statement. You've constructed the sets $E = B_d(x_1,\delta)$ and $F=X - Cl(B_d(x_1,\delta))$ which are open in $X$ and disjoint, so far, ok! But why do $E$ and $F$ separete S? In order to separate $S$ we need to make sure that $S = E\cup F$ and I couldn't see that.

@JoelMarques Strictly, we need to find two non-empty, disjoint sets $E', F'$ that are open in $S$ (under the subspace topology it inherits from $X$) and satisfy $S = E' \cup F'$. It suffices to find $E, F \subseteq X$ such that $S \subseteq E \cup F$, and such that $S$ is disjoint from $E \cap F$, which I have done in my answer. To be strict, simply take $E' = S \cap E$ and $F' = S \cap F$ to confirm the formal definition of separation of the subspace $S$.

You can verify that the $E$ and $F$ are such that $E \cup F$ is the entire space $X$ (since there exists no $x \in X$ such that $d (x_1, x) = \delta$), and that $E \cap F = \emptyset$ (since $E$ is the interior and $F$ is the exterior of the same set).
